# Differentiate between two radio groups in same XML layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having two radio group inside same xml layout. I am using oncheckedChanged listener in my MainActivity.java file. I want to differentiate between the two Radio groups using its listener. How to make use of parameter of RadioGroup Inside the Listener.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    switch (checkedId) {

    case R.id.rexcellent:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "execellnt",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case R.id.rverygood:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "very good",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case R.id.rgood:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        break;
    case R.id.raverage:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "average",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case R.id.rmale:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Male",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case R.id.rfemale:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "female",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

    }

}
```

here is my Xml code :

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rate Smartherd Tutorials ?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rexcellent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Excellent" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rverygood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Very Good" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rgood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Good" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/raverage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Average" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android1:id="@+id/textView2"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:text="How is shreks ?" />

<RadioGroup
    android1:id="@+id/rg2"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android1:id="@+id/rmale"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:checked="true"
        android1:text="MALE" />

    <RadioButton
        android1:id="@+id/rfemale"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:text="Female" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to use switch case statement only. And want to know the use of having  "RadioGroup group " inside the listener. What is the role of that?

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote? Please mention the reason.

Comment: Someone is having fun with down vote. Dont know who downvoted it

Comment: just use group.getId()

Comment: @pskink Do i have to use two switch case statements? one outer to differentiate between groups and one inner? and how?

Comment: in your case you don't have to use two switches since every radio button has its unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RadioGroup group` is the `RadioGroup` that originates the click event. However, in your particular case, I think it would be much more clear to have two separate event handlers because there is absolutely no code reuse between the two different radio groups.

Comment: alright my code is working absoulutely fine.... But justt want to know if we want to differentiate between two radio groups  without creating separate two listener in MainActivity.jave...is it possible?

Comment: @user3763594 Yes it is possible, and perfectly acceptable when the two radio groups are similar in some way. In this case, your two radio groups have nothing in common and so it is preferable to have two separate listeners.